# R grep with regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to define all appropriate data frame columns as factors and the creteria that I have includes what's NOT (by a list of ngrams, see below the code snippet) a factor:

```
data.clean[,names(data.clean)[grep("^[^time]*[^tot]*[^count]*[^score]*[^include]*[^has]*[^__fe]*$", 
            names(data.clean))]] 
<- as.factor(as.character(data.clean[,names(data.clean)[grep("^[^time]*[^tot]*[^count]*[^score]*[^include]*[^has]*[^__fe]*$", 
                                      names(data.clean))]]))
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick.
Any suggestions why?
thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
grep("^[^time]*[^tot]*[^count]*[^score]*[^include]*[^has]*[^__fe]*$", names(data.clean))
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. [^time]* is will match any sequence of characters that does not include 't','i','m' or 'e' anywhere. So the complete expression is anything that matches any of those complemented character classes. For example, `abbbccdde` will match that expression.

I think what you actually want is :

```
grep("^(time|tot|count|score|include|has|__fe)$", names(data.clean), invert=TRUE)
```

This pattern will match exactly the specified ngrams and invert=TRUE will return the complement of the matches, i.e. all the words that did not match the specified ngrams.